# is it possible to set the default value of std::tr1::tuple?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, std

(i'm using Visual C+++ 2010)
suppose i have defined a tuple like this:

```
typedef std::tr1::tuple<
int      //i want to set its default value to 9
, double //i want to set its default value to 3.3
, int    //i want to set its default value to 2
, double //i want to set its default value to -7.2
> Mytuple;
```

i can do that in a struct. but i wonder if it is possible to do that in `std::tr1::tuple`.
Besides, i want to know when shoud i use `std::tr1:tuple` or `struct?`

anyone can help me?

Comment: My general advice is to avoid tuples.  Except in contrived examples, they make code considerably harder to read all for the sake of saving a few lines in a header file.

Comment: If this is a requirement of your type, make a new type.

Comment: FYI: If you're using VS2010, you should *not* be using `std::tr1::tuple`. You should be using `std::tuple` (even if it's a `using` alias from the `tr1` namespace, it may not be later. And your code will be compatible with the "not VS" world).

Comment: tuple shouldn't be used when you know the number of fields. Use it only for variadic things.

Comment: @Dani : I could not disagree more. Even functional languages that have tuples as an absolutely _primary, core_ data structure do not support variadic pattern matching on tuples. Tuples should be used when it would simply be more code to write a new proper type than it's worth (e.g. very localized code).

Comment: @Dani In fact for some small internal mere value containers I sometimes prefer it, since MSVC's refusal to automatically generate move members can be really annyoing for such simple structs.

Comment: Despite the fact that stdlib != STL, `tuple` has exactly *nothing* to do with STL (as in: calling `vector` *STL* **can** be acceptable in some situations, because it was in STL. `tuple` wasn't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `tuple` is not a magical replacement for a struct. Their purposes are very different. A struct is, first and foremost, a language construct. A `tuple` is a *library* construct.

Structs get to have default values because the language says that you can write constructors to give them default values. The language then takes responsibility to call that constructor to initialize the struct. `tuple`, as a *library* construct, has no such capabilities, anymore than you can give `std::vector<T>` a default `T` that it will always automatically use. You can provide initial values for each member, but you can't give it *defaults*.

And if you think about it, you wouldn't want to. Imagine if someone could say that every `tuple<int, float>` was *always* created with 3 and 54.221. Even if some other code created it that knew nothing about this rule, it would have to be followed, (just as constructors for the type are used everywhere that type is used). Remember: every `tuple<int, float>` is the same type.

Really, a `tuple` is a substitute for the inability to perform reflection on a struct and do compile-time iteration over its members. The other main reason they exist is to be able to have compile-time dynamic structures (that is, the ability to create aggregates of types based on compile-time arguments, rather than a static list directly written into a file).

So unless you need to use `std::tie` (for effectively returning multiple values), iteration over members (ie: call some template function for each member of an object), or some similar specialized code, you should be using a struct.

Comment: @Xeo: What is "piecewise construction"?

Comment: @NicolBolas where can I learn about using `tuple` to do compile-time iteration over class members, and compile-time dynamic structures?

Comment: @Seth: You can do the first only indirectly if the class exposes its members as a tuple, and for the second, think what `bind` needs to do to store bound arguments. NicolBolas: An example would be `std::pair`s converting two parameter ctor. If you pass tuples, those are directly forwarded to the stored types. If you pass `std::piecewise_construct` as an extra first parameter, you get the contents of the tuples passed to the types.

Comment: @Xeo: That's effectively an extension of not being able to iterate over members of a struct. You use a tuple to hold the parameter rather than a struct only because you can effectively unpack the tuples into parameters to the constructors. You can't do that with structs due to a lack of compile-time reflection.

Comment: One other *practical* use (as in, it works in practice, but is not guaranteed in theory) I have for tuples is as an EBCO-in-a-package container, because at least libc++'s and libstdc++'s implementations give you that (dunno about MSVC, but I hope it does too), i.e. they optimize away the storage needed for empty members of the tuples.