# tuple - get_or helper function

Tags: c++, tuples, template-meta-programming, boost-fusion

I need a tuple helper function that if a requested type does not exist in the tuple it returns a default constructed null type.

e.g.

```
std::tuple<bool, int> tuple(true, 0);

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(get_or<double, std::nullptr_t>(tuple)), 
                           std::nullptr_t>::value, "");
assert(get_or<double, std::nullptr_t>(tuple) == nullptr);
```

I guess I need some boost fusion magic but I haven't quite figured it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: You first line shouldn't compile. You need to pass a second constructor argument.

Comment: @juanchopanza - I think that the first line is actually the question. He wants to be able to initialize the tuple like that and have the 2nd argument be set to it's default

Comment: @asafrob Ah OK. The way the problem is presented threw me. No helper function will fix that compiler error.

Comment: I think this is the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301863/is-it-possible-to-set-the-default-value-of-stdtr1tuple

Comment: @juanchopanza: You are right. I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tuple_index` helper I have lying around, which returns the index of a given type in a `std::tuple`. (It can easily be adjusted to work with a predicate such as `is_convertible`.)

```
template< typename elem, typename tup, std::size_t offset = 0 >
struct tuple_index
    : std::integral_constant< std::size_t, offset > {};

template< typename elem, typename head, typename ... tail, std::size_t offset >
struct tuple_index< elem, std::tuple< head, tail ... >, offset >
    : std::integral_constant< std::size_t, tuple_index< elem, std::tuple< tail ... >, offset + 1 >::value > {};

template< typename elem, typename ... tail, std::size_t offset >
struct tuple_index< elem, std::tuple< elem, tail ... >, offset >
    : std::integral_constant< std::size_t, offset > {};
```

You could build on it like this:

```
template< typename result, typename fallback, typename tuple >
typename std::enable_if< tuple_index< result, typename std::decay< tuple >::type >::value
                         == std::tuple_size< typename std::decay< tuple >::type >::value,
    fallback >::type
get_or( tuple && t ) { return {}; }

template< typename result, typename fallback, typename tuple >
typename std::enable_if< tuple_index< result, typename std::decay< tuple >::type >::value
                         != std::tuple_size< typename std::decay< tuple >::type >::value,
    result >::type
get_or( tuple && t ) {
    return std::get< tuple_index< result, typename std::decay< tuple >::type >::value >
        ( std::forward< tuple >( t ) );
}
```

http://ideone.com/ZdoWI7

All the `decay` is necessary because the metafunctions discriminate between `tuple` and `tuple &`.

Comment: Great! Though I was hoping on a simpler a helper function using boost mpl or fusion?

Comment: This is quite simple already, just verbose due to `decay` which I copy-pasted. You could factor it out by dispatching through an intermediary. Also I sort of doubt `forward` is doing anything; i just added it defensively.